# Does Beerus have the "Ultra Ego" ability?

Tags: dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball-manga

The Dragon Ball Wikia claims (without any  reference) Beerus used "Ultra Ego" when fighting Vegeta

[Ultra Ego](https://dragonball.fandom.com/wiki/Ultra_Ego_(ability))

However, nothing at that time stated that Beerus was using Ultra Ego, and Vegeta named his transformation later in the manga in the fight with Granola. Also, the only thing that it was stated by that time is that Beerus taught Vegeta the power of destruction.

Now, since in the battle with Granola Vegeta uses the power of destruction and a transformation called Ultra Ego at the same time, they are apparently implying this transformation powers are also part of what Beerus taught Vegeta, but Vegeta's transformation is visually different to that of Beerus and the others gods of destruction, with an aura surrounded by flames and changes in the shape of his face.

Is there any reference / explicit mention in the manga or whatever (source material, writer reference, etc.) that Beerus also uses "Ultra Ego", or is this just an assumption/conclusion made by the Wikia?

Answer (score 2):

It is an assumption, yes, but since Beerus was looking to show Vegeta the power of Ultra Ego, it is extremely probable he was using Ultra Ego at the moment. Beerus may not need to explicitly transform to use it and may have used Ultra Ego in previous chapters ; after all, Angels have been shown to use Ultra Instinct without transforming either.